# Changing group permissions for multiple folders and files in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have main folder in which I have multiple folders and files.
Main folder has owner X and group permission Y.
Inside it all folders and files have owner X and group permission x.
But I want all of them to have group permission Y also like the main folder.
What's the shortest way to make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what I needed to solve the problem:

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the group, without changing the owner, you can use

```
chgrp -R GROUP FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the -R option that will apply your permissions recursively(i.e. file and folders under the parent folders). It goes like this:

```
chmod -R <permissions> /myfolder
```

Comment: but I just want to change group permission

Comment: Yep. -R applies to chown too.